# iAd revenue randomly decreases

Tags: ios, iad

Hi I am a new iOS developer with my first app in the App Store implementing iAd. I have been watching the iAd console that displays my revenue for each day and total revenue. My question is, why might my total revenue be going down even though the average eCPM has not gone down since I last checked. I had more money.yestersay than I do today according to the posted total revenue and was just curious if anyone could fill me in? Thanks !

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as solved if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have an app with iAd in the *App* *Store* too. I never really got into the reason for some changes in eCPM but I noticed that at the end of the day it seemed like I got the same amount of money as the days before. I guess apples system is not always as precise in this things. I would suggest you to just wait and see if everything comes back in place. :)